# NSCalendarUnit. NSSecondCalendarUnit deprecation message wrong?

Tags: swift

```
@available(OSX, introduced=10.4, deprecated=10.10, message="Use NSCalendarUnitSecond instead")
public static var NSSecondCalendarUnit: NSCalendarUnit { get }
```

"Use NSCalendarUnitSecond instead"
should be
"Use NSCalendarUnit.Second instead"?

Comment: NSCalendarUnit.Second

Answer (score 0):

The Swift definition and the availability statement are synthesized from the C definition in the Foundation header file "NSCalendar.h":

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, NSCalendarUnit) {
     // ...
     NSCalendarUnitSecond             = kCFCalendarUnitSecond,
     // ...
     NSSecondCalendarUnit NS_CALENDAR_ENUM_DEPRECATED(10_4, 10_10, 2_0, 8_0, "Use NSCalendarUnitSecond instead") = NSCalendarUnitSecond,
     // ...
}
```

and the result is

```
public struct NSCalendarUnit : OptionSetType {
    // ...
    public static var Second: NSCalendarUnit { get }
    // ...
    @available(OSX, introduced=10.4, deprecated=10.10, message="Use NSCalendarUnitSecond instead")
    public static var NSSecondCalendarUnit: NSCalendarUnit { get }
    // ...
}
```

The deprecation message is just a string

```
"Use NSCalendarUnitSecond instead"
```

and the Swift compiler is not so smart that it can substitute
`NSCalendarUnitSecond` by the corresponding Swift definition
`NSCalendarUnit.Second` within that message. So from the
Swift view, this message is misleading.

But you are right, in Swift you have to use `NSCalendarUnit.Second`,
or just `.Second` if the enumeration type can be inferred from
the context.